# In C#, A procedure that modifies the incoming array?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to write a procedure that modifies the incoming array by filling it with the value provided. Since this is a procedure, I think it might not return anything. Instead, I will have to modify the array directly, and because arrays are reference type variables, the array will be permanently changed even after this procedure. I need to set each integer in the numbers array with the integer value.

I am not quite sure how I should solve this problem. I was able to come up with how the the input and output should look like.

Example Input:
{ 22.6, 45.2, 17.9 }, 10

Example Output:
{ 10, 10, 10 }

Comment: What have you tried?  This is fairly straight-forward in C# and you are kind of on the right mental track, but a few simple tests in code would give you the answer.  Show what you have tried, and what isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to [so], I think **you need to pick a beginners programming book**. Also check out [ask] and the [FAQ]'s for general guidelines on what questions are suitable - as it stands this question is too broad and its off-topic in that you don't explain how to get 10,10,10 from { 22.6, 45.2, 17.9 }, 10... you are asking about the basic building blocks of voids vs functions and by val or by ref, we at least need the code you have. Good luck!

Comment: i've tried calling the procedure as follow: int [] numbers = {22.6, 45.2, 17.9, 10}; SortNumbers(numbers); but i don't think thats the correct approach

Comment: I think you mean to say "arrays are reference type _values_" and are mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If i understand you right..

void Test8(int[] numbers, int value)
{
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.Length;i++)
    {
        numbers[i] =(double) value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be although the test problem already comes with this line of code: public void Test8(int[] numbers, int value] which I think the array is inside of that line of code.

Comment: the cast of n to a double is unnecessary.

Comment: i preffer explicit casting.

Comment: it says that keyword "void" cannot be used in this context.

Comment: try adding "public" before